# How to prevent a react parent component from loading

Tags: reactjs

I am using react to build my app and on the post component there are 3 other  child components that are been called in a map function while passing the post props.

On the list component when a user clicks on the like button the post tends to reload, and that is not what I want.

This is my post parent component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class Posts extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            sidebaropen: false,
            test: '',
            posts: []
        }
    }


    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

        if (nextProps.post.posts.length > 0) {

            this.setState({ posts: nextProps.post.posts })
            console.log('updated')
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getPosts();

        socket.on('posts', data => {
            console.log("resiving :" + JSON.stringify(data))
            if (Object.keys(this.state.posts).length > 0 && Object.keys(data).length >
                0) {

                this.setState({ posts: [data[0], ...this.state.posts] })
            } else {
                this.setState({ posts: data })
            }


        })

        socket.on('id', data => {
            console.log(data)

        })
        console.log('mounted post')
    }
}
render(){

    const { loading } = this.props.post;
    const { posts, } = this.state;
    let closebtn
    let postContent;

    if (posts === null || loading) {
        postContent = <Spinner />;
    } else {
        postContent = <PostFeeds posts={ posts } />;
    }
    if (this.state.sidebaropen) {

        closebtn = <button className='close-toggle-btn' onClick =
            { this.closetoggleclickhandle } />
      }

    return (

        <div className= "post_wrapper" >
        <Postsidebar show={ this.state.sidebaropen } />
            < div className = "" >
                { postContent }
                < /div>
    { closebtn }

    <TiPlus className='creat-post-toggle-btn icons'  onClick =
        { this.toggleclickhandle } />
        </div>
      )
}
     }

Posts.propTypes = {
    getPosts: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    post: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    post: state.post
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getPosts })(Posts);
```

and this is the first child component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import PostItem from './PostItem';

class PostFeeds extends Component {


    componentDidMount() {
        //this.setState({ test : 'mounted'})
        console.log('mounted feed')

    }
    render() {

        const { posts } = this.props;
        //console.log(posts)
        return posts.map(post => <PostItem key={ post._id } post = { post } />);

    }
}
```

postItem.js its i little kind of rough

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { deletePost, addLike, removeLike, bookmark } from "../../actions/postsActions";
import Postimg from './Postimg';
import {  MdBookmarkBorder ,/**MdBookmark */} from "react-icons/md";
import {AiFillDislike, AiOutlineLike, AiFillDownSquare} from 'react-icons/ai'
import { TiHeartOutline, TiHeartFullOutline, TiMessage,  TiDelete } from "react-icons/ti";


class PostItem extends Component {
  onDeleteClick(id){
    this.props.deletePost(id);

  }
  componentWillMount() {
    console.log( 'mounted item')
    //console.log(window.scrollTo(0, localStorage.getItem('scrollpossition')))
  }
  onLikeClick(id){
    this.props.addLike(id);
   // window.scrollTo(0, localStorage.getItem('scrollpossition'))
    window.location.href = '/feed'
  }
  onUnlikeClick(id){
    this.props.removeLike(id);
   // window.scrollTo(0, localStorage.getItem('scrollpossition'))
    window.location.href = '/feed'
  }
  findUserLike(likes) {
    const { auth } = this.props;
    if(likes.length > 0){
      if(likes.filter(like => like.user === auth.user.id).length > 0) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  findUserDislike(dislikes) {
    const { auth } = this.props;
    if(dislikes.length > 0){
      if(dislikes.filter(dislike => dislike.user === auth.user.id).length > 0) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  onBookmark (id){
    this.props.bookmark(id)
  }
  render() {

    const { post, auth, showActions } = this.props;
    let ifAlreadyliked;
    let ifAlreadydisliked;
    let postimg;
    let postText;
    let profileimg
    let topic = ''

    if(post.user)
    {
       if(post.user.profileImageData){
        profileimg =  <Link to={`/profile/${post.profile.handle}`}><img src={post.profile.profileImageData} alt=''  /></Link> 

       }else{
        profileimg =  <img src='/assets/images/user-4.png' alt='pip'  />
       }
      if(this.findUserLike(post.likes)){
        ifAlreadyliked =  <TiHeartFullOutline className= 'icons like-color'/>
      }else{
        ifAlreadyliked =  <TiHeartOutline className= 'icons'/>
      }
      if(this.findUserDislike(post.dislikes)){
        ifAlreadydisliked =  <AiFillDislike className= 'icons yellow'/>
      }else{
        ifAlreadydisliked =  <AiOutlineLike  className= 'icons'   onClick={this.onUnlikeClick.bind(this, post._id)}/>
      }
     }
     if(post.Topic){
     topic =  <div className= ''><small><b style={{color:'#ff8d00'}}>< AiFillDownSquare />{post.Topic}</b></small></div>
    }
      if(post.postImageData !== '' && post.postImageData !== null && post.postImageData !== undefined)
      {
      postimg = <Postimg imageSrc = {post.postImageData} imgAlt = {''}/>

      }
      if(post.text !== '' || post.text === null)
      {
      postText =  <div className='feed_text'>{post.text}</div>
      }


    return (

        <div className="feed_card">
          <div className="feed_header">
          <div className="feed-profile-img">{profileimg}</div>
            <div className="feed-handle-text">{post.name}</div>

            <div className='v-spacer'/>
            <div className="time-stamp"><small>{new Date (post.date).toLocaleString ('en-US', {hour: 'numeric', hour12: true, minute: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' } )} </small></div>

          </div>
          <div className="feed-body-container">
         <div>
              {topic}
              {postimg}
              {postText}
              <div className='mini_feed_footer'>
                <small>{post.likes.length} likes. {post.comments.length} comments. {post.dislikes.length} dislikes.</small>
              </div>
            { showActions ? (
                  <div className='feed_footer'>

                    <div onClick={this.onLikeClick.bind(this, post._id)} type="button" className="btn btn-light mr-1">
                          <div className='feed-icon-mini-container'>
                            {ifAlreadyliked}
                          </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className='spacer'/>

                    {ifAlreadydisliked}


                    <div className='spacer'/>

                    <Link to={`/post/${post._id}`} className='header-brand'>
                      <TiMessage className='icons'/>
                    </Link>

                    <div className='spacer'/>
                      { post.user === auth.user.id ? (

                        <TiDelete
                          onClick={this.onDeleteClick.bind(this, post._id)}
                          className="icons red"
                        />

                    ) :  <MdBookmarkBorder
                        onClick={this.onBookmark.bind(this, post._id)}
                        className="icons blue"
                      /> }

            </div>) : null}

          </div>
          </div>
        </div>

    );
  }
}
PostItem.defaultProps = {
  showActions: true
}

PostItem.propTypes = {
  post: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  deletePost: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  addLike:PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  removeLike:PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  bookmark:PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {deletePost, addLike,bookmark, removeLike})(PostItem);
```

Comment: why don't you want parent component reload? if it doesn't reload then neither of the child will reload.

Comment: The problem is the you have have `postContent` being reassigned on every render so if nothing changes still this will re-render because your `postContent` objects reference would be different on each re-render thus react thinks state as react compares shallow

Comment: so is there any possible way around it??

Comment: but when a post is deleted it dose not re render

Comment: then please show complete code, something is wrong with `PostItem`.

Comment: i just did that now

Comment: let me check. your onLikeClick()

Comment: Got it. One big issue is the use of `window.location.href = "/feed"` this does the reload, replace it with `this.props.history.push('/feed')` and a minor fix is to bind the handlers in constructor or make them arrow functions.

Comment: that didnt work either i tried commenting it it seams the component still reloads even without any that statement

Comment: can you make a sandbox of it? https://codesandbox.io/dashboard/recent

Comment: sorry for not saying this earlier on but its just a guest do u think the problem might be from my reducers ??

Comment: page reload is not because of reducers. reload means when page refreshes. Yes re-renders can occur due to reducers as they change state. but I don't see any reducers being used.

Comment: I am not familiar with sand box

Comment: it's similar to vscode but on web. Used to collaborate on projects and showing code for bugs fixes etc

Comment: I hope you resolve it soon, may be I missed something. I will recheck this in morning. Good Night.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use window object for navigation (Major) as this causes reload. Make your handlers arrow functions (minor).

```
onLikeClick = id => {
   this.props.addLike(id);
   // window.scrollTo(0, localStorage.getItem('scrollpossition'))
   this.props.history.push("/feed");
};

onUnlikeClick = id => {
   this.props.removeLike(id);
   // window.scrollTo(0, localStorage.getItem('scrollpossition'))
   this.props.history.push("/feed");
};
```

Also if `/feed` is the same page then remove it all together, no need for it.

Comment: I did try this but still the same issue.

Comment: i just updated the cod from the parent to the last component

Comment: that didnt work either i tried commenting it it seams the component still reloads even without any that statement